# Простейшая задача по HTML, поиск внутри iframe

Tags: html

Только-только начал изучать HTML и столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Хочу сделать простейшую html страничку, в которой есть `<iframe>` и `<form>`. В форме: текстовое поле и кнопка отправки запроса. Идея какая — написать что-то в текстовое поле, нажать "отправить" и в `<iframe>` увидеть страницу с результатами поиска.

Пока написал такое:

```
<body>
    <iframe name="AAA" width="600" height="300"> </iframe>
    <form  action="www.google.com" method="get" target="AAA">
        <input type="text"  name="text" size="20" value="что-то">
        <input type="submit" value="Искать">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: на чистой хтмл это не получиться, необходим обработчик

Answer (score 1):

^^^^^ Я бы не спешил так утверждать:

```
<iframe src="" id="myframe" width="600" height="300"></iframe>
<br />
<input id="mydata" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="document.getElementById('myframe').src ='http://www.bing.com/search?q='+getElementById('mydata').value;" />
```

Фиддл: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/4qET6/

Comment: Ну, дык это ж не просто HTML, тут еще очень даже и JavaScript.